# VB.NET Throws Exception

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, exception

In Java you can mark a method as might throw an exception
e.g. 'public void foo() throws exception {'
This is useful as the developer can then see to putting that method in a try catch block.

Is there a way to do this in VB.NET so that Visual Studio (as in Eclipse) warns the developer to put this code in a try catch block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent. 
Its pretty stupid actually, because exceptions should be exceptionnal.

Just add it in the XML documentation.

Dont forget that the throws in Java forces the calling method to surround the call by a try catch bloc ...

Comment: There are many cases, especially involving race conditions, where exceptions may be semi-expected.  Checked exceptions could be useful in such contexts, if there were better ways of identifying the semi-expected exceptions and declaratively specifying that they should be wrapped (without having to use lots of catch/wrap/rethrow code).